# The use of "as"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My question: In the following sentence, what part of speech is the word **as**?

> He visited the United Nations, or the UN, **as** it is more commonly called.

Is it merely a conjunction? If it is not, what part of speech is it?

Comment: Perhaps I should explain:  I teach English in China, and Chinese teachers of English grammar say that in this sentence, 'as' is a relative pronoun.  That is what prompted me to ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

"as" is a function word which has multiple uses. So it is necessary to get a survey about its uses. As a conjunction introducing a clause it can have temporal, causal and comparative use. As already said it can be a preposition and an adverb. And there are special word groups with "as", eg such as, as to, as if/as though and others.

The best way to study "as" is a big dictionary. In grammars the word is treated in a lot of different paragraphs.The Longman DCE (Dictionary of Contemporary English) has four numbers for "as" as a preposition and a special information box about word choice: as, like, as if.
"as" as a conjunction has 17 numbers.

As to your question in "as it is more commonly called" "as" is a comparative conjunction.

Answer (score -1):

it might be a conjunction here, but it is quite versatile.

it can be used as an adverb, conjunction or preposition.

adverb - do as he tells you

conjunction - as I came in, he flew.

preposition - you are not as tall as me

Comment: Is this really an answer to the OP's question? Which of the *possibilities* is most likely the case in the OP's example?

Comment: it is a conjunction, isn't it? correct me if I'm wrong.
:-)

Comment: *might* is a hedgey word. Which do you think it is? It's not really my job to answer the question for you. If you offer an **answer**, it should be supportable, not a guess.

Comment: In "Do as he tells you" I  would say "as" is a conjunction of comparison as it introduces a clause. It is not an adverb.

Comment: I guess I was desultory and didn't ruminate before typing the stuff. my bad.

Comment: come to think of it, you're right. I voted. thanks.